# Upload file to cloudinary in Laravel

Tags: php, cloudinary, laravel-9, php-8.1

> error
> :
> exception
> :
> "Error"
> file
> :
> "C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\hotel-app\app\Http\Controllers\LoggedInUserController.php"
> line
> :
> 14
> message
> :
> "Class "Cloudinary" not found"
> trace
> :
> (35) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
> [[Prototype]]
> :
> Object
> headers
> :
> HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
> message
> :
> "Http failure response for http://localhost:8000/api/editProfile: 500 Internal Server Error"
> name
> :
> "HttpErrorResponse"
> ok
> :
> false
> status
> :
> 500
> statusText
> :
> "Internal Server Error"
> url
> :
> "http://localhost:8000/api/editProfile"
> [[Prototype]]
> :
> HttpResponseBase

I keep getting this error.
Please, which cloudinary class am i supposed to include in my controller to get file upload to cloudinary done

Answer (score 1):

be sure to add sniped code below to : `config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Cloudinary' => CloudinaryLabs\CloudinaryLaravel\Facades\Cloudinary::class,
    ...
]
```

Comment: After adding that snipped code to my config/app.php, I tried uploading again and here is this error   "message": "Class \"CloudinaryLabs\\CloudinaryLaravel\\Facades\\Cloudinary\" not found", please I need clarifications

Comment: do you install this package :
composer require cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel